# jquery closest li doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i have html page with a link

when user clicked that link a new select tag should be appeared

## html code

```
<div class="container" id="addCell">
    <ul class="containerUL">
        <li class="containerLI">
            <p>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>City</label>
                <select id="countrySelector">
                </select>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="containerLI">
            <p>
                <label>Inserted cells</label>
                <a href="#" class="smallLink" id="acaclink">new</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="containerLI">
            <input type="submit" class="button1" value="save"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## jquery code

```
$("#addCell").ready(function(){
    $("#addCell").on('click',"#acaclink",function(){
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCells/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>select cell</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $(this).closest('li').append('<p>\n\
            <label>Select Cell</label>\n\
            <select name="acSelect[]">\n\
             '+options+'\n\
</select>\n\
            </p>');
        });
    });
});
```

1- i am check the JSON call and there is no error 
2- i am alert option and it works as i want

my question is : when i replace `$(this).closes('li')` with `$('ul').append`
it works , but when i put closest li it doesn't . where is the mistake please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `$(this)` inside anonymous function has another scope and refers to another object

```
$("#addCell").ready(function(){
    $("#addCell").on('click',"#acaclink",function(){
        var me = this; // we use "me" as a closure to the object we clicked at

        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCells/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>select cell</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $(me).closest('li').append('<p>\n\   // <---- here we use "me"
            <label>Select Cell</label>\n\
            <select name="acSelect[]">\n\
             '+options+'\n\
</select>\n\
            </p>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it works , thank you very much i will accept your answer when after 9 mins

Answer (score 1):

`this` has a different meaning inside the `getJSON` callback.

You can keep a reference outside the `getJSON`, then use it inside.

```
$("#addCell").ready(function(){
    $("#addCell").on('click',"#acaclink",function(){

        var that = this; // reference this

        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCells/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>select cell</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }

              // use it here
            $(that).closest('li').append('<p>\n\
            <label>Select Cell</label>\n\
            <select name="acSelect[]">\n\
             '+options+'\n\
</select>\n\
            </p>');
        });
    });
});
```

Or use `$.ajax` and its `context` property.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCells/TRUE",
        context:this,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){

          // your code
            $(this).closest('li').append('<p>\n\...'

        }
    });
```

This is equivalent to your code since `getJSON` is just a wrapper for this, but you get all the options available to you, like `context:`.